# Order-preserving surjective map $f: {\cal P}(\omega)/(fin) \to [0,1]$

Tags: order-theory, posets, lattice-theory

Is there an order-preserving surjective map $f: {\cal P}(\omega)/(fin) \to [0,1]$? Or from ${\cal P}(\omega)/(fin)$ onto $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Upper density? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density

Comment: Do you mean $\leq$-preserving or $<$-preserving?

Comment: The title and the body ask two completely different questions.

Comment: @AndreasThom Thank you for your question - I mean $\leq$-preserving

Comment: @AsafKaragila both the title and the body are about "order-preserving surjective map $f: {\cal P}(\omega)/(fin) \to [0,1]$" (and the body asks one more similar question) - or did I miss something? Or I didn't get that yours was a humourous remark?

Comment: Last time I checked, $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$ – while similar, are still quite different.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's right, but I ask about $[0,1]$ in both body and title. So the body is an extension of the title (which is true for many MO questions). But yeah, maybe it is wrong to ask more than $1$ question in a MO question, but that would be something for https://meta.mathoverflow.net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace $\omega$ with $X:=\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$, and map each $A\subseteq X$ to $\limsup A\in [0,1]$.  $\limsup$ is weakly increasing, and invariant under finite changes. This map is onto $[0,1]$.

If you want to map onto the dyadic rationals, partition $\omega$ into countably many infinite sets $\omega=A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup\cdots$, and map each set $B\subseteq \omega$ to

- $\sum_{n\in I_B} 2^{-n}$, if $I_B:=\{n: B \cap A_n \mbox{ infinite}\}$ is finite
- $1$, if $I_B$ is infinite.

If you want a map onto $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$, compose with some isomorphism.